# VBA Excel: return the parent workbook of a range

Tags: vba, excel

How do I return the name of the Workbook that contains a given range?

`Range.Parent` gives the parent sheet.... is the parent workbook possible? Something to the effect of `Range.ParentWorkbook`

Comment: After you get the sheet, just do parent on that? Guessing you want it in one step?

Comment: @findwindow create answer and get points

Comment: lol I have enough points and it's my pleasure to help ^_^ Thank you though! Edit: I don't think I deserve any anyways. Wasn't exactly enlightening XD If I had code to do it all in one line then yea...

Comment: Hope I didn't offend you earlier. Just didn't feel like I deserved points XD

Answer (score 6):

Coming late to the party, note that this can be also done in one line (tested in Excel 2010):

```
myRange.Worksheet.Parent.name
```

Macro Man's GetWorkbookName() function would be simply:

```
Private Function GetWorkbookName(myRange As Excel.Range) As String
    GetWorkbookName = myRange.Worksheet.Parent.name
End Function
```

example use is the same:

```
Sub Foo()
    Dim parentWorkbookName As String

    parentWorkbookName = GetWorkbookName(Range("A1"))
    MsgBox parentWorkbookName
End Sub
```

Comment: Or just use `MyRange.Parent.Name` gives sheet name, `MyRange.Parent.Parent.Name` gives book name, `MyRange.Parent.Parent.Parent.Name` gives the Excel application.

Answer (score 0):

findwindow's comment as an example (post is community wiki - not taking credit for it)

You could create a UDF like so that takes a `Range` as an argument:

```
Private Function GetWorkbookName(myCell As Excel.Range) As String
    Dim a As Excel.Worksheet
    Set a = myCell.Parent
    GetWorkbookName = a.Parent.Name
End Function
```

example use:

```
Sub Foo()
    Dim parentWorkbookName As String

    parentWorkbookName = GetWorkbookName(Range("A1"))
    MsgBox parentWorkbookName
End Sub
```